# Wow, the iOS app feed sure showed me an interesting question! I want to read more. Uh, how do I get there?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, ios-app, navigation, ios-app-feed

In the iOS app, pulling up a question from the feed gives the standard question view, which provides no means of navigating elsewhere on that site, either to browse or search. This should be changed for feed questions.

For example, I tapped on a highlighted Seasoned Advice question today, and found that I wanted to make a comment pointing to a related question on the site. The best way I could think of finding that post was to leave the app and use my browser. Then I came back with the link to copy-paste in.

Similarly, a question in the feed might be so intriguing that I want to look around for more cool stuff on the site. That requires two taps back and then a search via the "All Sites" menu item.

I'd suggest that questions selected from the feed should get a special header bar (or maybe stuck in between the questions and the answers) that provides a "More posts!" link at least to the site's top view; ideally there would also be a search field that could pop out of it.

Another possibility that would work pretty well, although it's a small tap target on a phone, would be to link the site name that appears under the question title to the site's top view.

Comment: Looks like the site icon of each feed item is a link to the site itself, have you missed it?

Comment: Ah ha, I _didn't_ know about that, @ShadowWizard! That's quite good, and it should do the trick. (One minor issue with it might be the feed changing -- and thus my losing the first quesiton -- while I'm searching.) I'll leave this request to meet its fate regardless.

Comment: Yeah, still no way to reach the site from the question itself. I think logical position would be the site name in the top middle of the page, what do you think?

Comment: Yes, it seems very sensible; it just might be too small a tap target.

Comment: I *always* accidentally click the site icon when I mean to click a feed item directly. Seems like that just isn't intuitive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is fixed in 1.4.4.1, shipping in mid-February.

I went ahead and added it in two places, both only in the case that you're viewing a question outside of its site scope (from the feed, inbox, achievements or if a question linked to a new site):

1. If you long press the question title in the navigation bar, like you suggested, we'll bring up a menu saying "Switch to Site".  Tapping this will be the same as selecting the site from the menu.
2. A new toolbar item called "Switch to Site" will also appear below the question in the same circumstances.  This will generally be in the "More" item.

I also made the site icon in the feed a little more useful (shipping in 1.4.3.7, soon).  If the feed was showing you unanswered questions, the site icons will take you to unanswered questions.  Otherwise it goes to hot questions.

Comment: Sounds good! Will mark as answered when it ships.